# Manipulating CSV data with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using Invoke-RestMethod to get data from a vendor in CSV format. The data is not in a format I need (it needs to be sent to another vendor) - there are four columns for each "set", and there can be any number of "sets" in the CSV - the column header names are not static - every four columns is a complete set.

Column1a, Column2a, Column3a, Column4a, Column1z, Column2z, Column3z, Column4z

data, data, data, data, data, data, data, data

What I need to do is export columns 1-4, 5-8, 9-12 etc. to separate CSV's. I do not even know where to begin for this.

[image]

Comment: You could look into ConvertFrom-CSV and then work on the array with Select-Object

Comment: Can you show any concrete data and how it should be transformed? You can provide fake data, as long as you preserve the idea behind it.

Comment: Post the data with the question so you can format it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```psh
$csv     = Import-Csv 'input.csv'
$headers = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties | select -Expand Name
$step    = 4

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $headers.Count; $i += $step) {
  $csv | select $headers[$i..($i+$step-1)] |
    Export-Csv "output_$($i/$step).csv" -NoType
}
```

`Import-Csv` creates a list of objects from the input file, where the CSV column names become the object property names. So you can extract the header names from an object by expanding the object's property names. Iterate over the header array with a step size of the number of columns you want to export per output file and use the range operator (`..`) to select the columns you want to export in the current iteration.

Comment: Your method of getting `$headers` gets past the issue I was having.  Good to know that option is there. Thanks. Looks like we have the same basic approach

Comment: This works great!  One more question: how would I remove the first two columns (header name not static) from one of the CSV's?  I had to save header[0] as header[3] and rename header[2], and no longer need header[0] and header[1]

Comment: @user3208164 Do the first export outside the loop (`$csv | select $headers[2,3] | Export-Csv 'output_0.csv' -NoType`) and start the loop with `$i = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Having sample data would be nice but I think the jist of the solution does not require it. Using your columns I created 4 column grouped data. First set contains letters, second contains numbers. In the end they will be in separate files.

```
Column1a, Column2a, Column3a, Column4a, Column1z, Column2z, Column3z, Column4z
A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4
A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4
A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4
A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4
A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4
A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4
```

So I am not concerned with how the data get there so I imported the data using `Get-Content` in my example to have that raw csv data which presumably you are getting from `Invoke-RestMethod`. Now we get the columns from that data by exracting the first row into `$header` assuming the column names are in the first row. If not you could use `Select -Index 2` if it was the second row. *Side Note* I thought i could get that from `Get-Member` but it put the columns in alphabetical order so that was scrapped although Ansgar Wiechers's answer handle this cleaner than mine.

After we ge the header we convert the data into an object for further processing. The magic comes from the loop which navigates the object in 4 column groups. **Caveat:** I am assuming that you have columns in multiples of 4 for this to work perfectly.

For the output just take the 4 columns we currently have in the `$groupHeaders` and join then into one string. Special characters could screw that one up. Easy to address with a little regex.

```
$outputPath = "C:\temp\"
$data = GC C:\temp\null.csv

#$header = $data | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$header = ($data | select -first 1).split(",") | ForEach-Object{$_.Trim()}
$data = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv 

$specialCharactersRegex = [regex]::Escape('"*/:<>?\|')

For($group = 1;$group -le ($header.Count / 4);$group++){

    $headerStartIndex = ($group - 1) * 4
    $groupHeaders = $header[$headerStartIndex..($headerStartIndex+3)]

    $data | Select @($groupHeaders) | Export-CSV "$outputPath$(($groupHeaders -join '') -replace $specialCharactersRegex).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

In the end of this I have the two files below which contain data from their respective columns.

```
Column1aColumn2aColumn3aColumn4a.csv
Column1zColumn2zColumn3zColumn4z.csv
```

Comment: The only thing I would worry about would be if the first line wasn't the actual headers, but a line containing typeinfo...

Comment: @HunterEidson good point. The OP would know that better once he tests with actual data. I will make note of my assumption.