# Delete first two columns in CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to delete the first two columns in a CSV. I do not know the header names, they are not static. I figured out how to remove the first two rows, but not the first two columns. The sample code I am working with is below

```powershell
$csv     = Import-Csv 'input.csv'
$headers = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties | select -Expand Name
$step    = 4

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $headers.Count; $i += $step) {
  $csv | select $headers[$i..($i+$step-1)] |
    Export-Csv "output_$($i/$step).csv" -NoType
}
```

Comment: I was about to refer you to your own question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320245/manipulating-csv-data-with-powershell. The answer is almost there.

Comment: In your code you are already deciding which columns end up in the CSV file. All you have to do is manage that `$headers[$i..($i+$step-1)]`

Comment: If you just want to remove the first 2 columns and then split the rest in groups of 4, pick one of the answers here. If you want the columns removed from the first CSV (leaving just 2 columns in that CSV) see my response to your comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27321887/1630171).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$csv     = Import-Csv 'input.csv'
$include = $csv[0].psobject.properties | select -ExpandProperty Name -Skip 2
$csv | select $include -skip 2 | export-csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

That should take care of pruning off the first 2 columns and then skipping the first 2 rows.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to skip the first X columns you just need to adjust your `$headers` statement

```powershell
$headers = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties | select -Skip 2 -Expand Name
```

The above would skip the first 2 columns by not processing the first 2 headers. The rest of the code will group columns of 4 after those 2.

Answer (score 2):

I think just changing the 0 in the for loop to a 2 should do it:

```
$csv     = Import-Csv 'input.csv'
$headers = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties | select -Expand Name
$step    = 4

for ($i = 2; $i -lt $headers.Count; $i += $step) {
  $csv | select $headers[$i..($i+$step-1)] |
    Export-Csv "new_output_$($i/$step).csv" -NoType
}
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks for the edit! I had apparently lost my mind when I tried to format the answer.